# what am I missing in my dateFormatter function?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to create a function to convert a String to Date in swift from an API. I've seen a lot of examples about that and tried to do the same but it always returns nil.

```
let dateStr = "1996-11-24T09:02:32Z"

func toDate(str: String) -> Date? {
    let dateForm = DateFormatter()
    dateForm.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    dateForm.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    let date = dateForm.date(from: str)
    return date
}


print(toDate(str: dateStr)) // always prints nil
```

I've tried to tweak, change location, remove location, change dateFormat but nothing works.

what might be wrong here?

thank you in advance

Comment: The string "1996-11-24T09:02:32Z" does not match the format "dd-MM-yyyy" ... You can find the date format specification here: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns.

Comment: You can use an `ISO8601DateFormatter` for that string

Comment: By the way, date formatters are relatively expensive to create, so you probably don’t want to create a new formatter every time you call `toDate`. It may be prudent to instantiate the date formatter once and re-use it every time you call `toDate`. And while I’d second dan’s suggestion to use `ISO8601DateFormatter`, if you are going to use `DateFormatter`, I’d suggest using the invariant locale of `en_US_POSIX`, not just `en_US`, as suggested in [TN1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since your date is `1996-11-24T09:02:32Z` and you are using formate `dd-MM-yyyy` which does not match. so you need to replace `dd-MM-yyyy` with `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` and it will work fine.

And your result will be:

```
let dateStr = "1996-11-24T09:02:32Z"

func toDate(str: String) -> Date? {
    let dateForm = DateFormatter()
    dateForm.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    dateForm.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    let date = dateForm.date(from: str)
    return date
}


print(toDate(str: dateStr)) // "Optional(1996-11-24 09:02:32 +0000)\n"
```

Or you can use short way as dan suggested:

```
func toDate(str: String) -> Date? {
    return ISO8601DateFormatter().date(from: str)
}

print(toDate(str: dateStr)) // "Optional(1996-11-24 09:02:32 +0000)\n"
```

Or if you prefer an `Extension`

```
extension Formatter {
    static let iso8601 = ISO8601DateFormatter()
}

let dateStr = "1996-11-24T09:02:32Z"
Formatter.iso8601.date(from: dateStr) // "Nov 24, 1996 at 2:32 PM"
```

Comment: The locale needs to be `en_US_POSIX`, not `en_US`.